# Weird output to text file using fprintf()

Tags: c, printf

In a simulation program I am trying to print the measures to a text file. The project is a combination of Java, C and C++ but the file I am working with is in C. The code for printing is as follows:

```
if(sample)
  fprintf(MeasureInfo->measuresFile, "%d: %f\n", count++, sample);
```

This works for part of the output but there are large bulks (about 100 to 1000 measures) of data that are not printed to the text file. Instead I see just a bulk of NULs in Sublime Text and 0-bytes in bless:

```
436: 0.851661
437: 0.043466
(Really large block of NUL all in one line).210402
751: 0.357543
752: 0.816120
```

I only worked with part of the code so far and thought it might be a concurrency problem. So I printed out all pids that access the function with getpid() and it gave me different ones (19036, 19037, 19038 for instance). I then tried to use pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock but it produced the same output.
Another thing I tried was using sleep after every 400 measures. This actually helped but shortened the number of measures the produced by a fourth.

Do you have any idea what the actual problem might be and how to fix it? I am really sorry if this is an answered or easy question but I tried and searched a while and didn't find a solution to this.

Comment: `fprintf` should never insert a NUL. Are you sure no other code is writing to the file, or seeking? Did you verify that `sample` is nonzero so the line isn't getting skipped? And note that the pthread library works on threads within, not between processes, so that lock won't do anything. Please give details about the interprocess aspect.

Comment: Do you realise that fprintf() is non-reantrant? printing from multiple threads, or printf() from within a signal handler could cause this kind of results.

Comment: Just to be clear, unsynchronized `fprintf` from two threads (or processes) to the same file is a no-no. There's no way the results could be well-defined, so corruption is inevitable. As long as each file is written by a linear sequence of operations, and each process calls `flush` when it finishes writing its part, you'll be OK.

Comment: So there is no way this could work concurrent? This is an old and large project with a complex structure and generated code. I would prefer to have a local solution. I could just let the processes write to different text files depending on their id.

Comment: @hyperspace Of course it can be fixed. But you have to give us some sort of description of who is trying to do the concurrent access. Writing to different files and merging afterwards would be a very reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I/O and multitasking are a dangerous combination. At the thread level, `fprintf` is writing into a buffer, in thread-unsafe fashion. The individual formatting components might overwrite each other, and when one call flushes the buffer while another is trying to write, the result is certain to be lost data. It could even cause a buffer overflow and crash right inside to `stdio` library.

At the process level, the buffers are getting flushed to particular locations in the file. If two processes try to write at the same time, they will clobber each others' results. A process typically doesn't poll the filesystem to check if a file is growing due to an outside influence, then seek to the new end before writing.

If you have a very large project and synchronizing all the I/O to this file isn't an option, consider assigning each thread or process its own file, and merge the files after the fact.

Comment: Thank you. A good conclusion for everyone with similar problems. Assigning each process its own file seems to be the best solution for the project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

`sample` looks to be a float or double. You shouldn't compare a floating point variable against a fixed value, as it most likely will never have this value. For floating point variable you should always compare against a delta. Your `if` clause will probably always be entered.

`fprintf` shouldn't print NUL though. Can you show the exact output (or part of it)?

Comment: It's a potential issue if output is supposed to be skipped, but it wouldn't cause any of the symptoms he describes.

Comment: @Potatoswatter At first I was thinking he might be close to a zero value, but that shouldn't result in NUL being printed. I assumed he meant lots of zero characters. Maybe I'm wrong, so he should show the output.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the delta. When I look at the file with the bless hexeditor it is a block of 0's. So for example: 30 33 33 39 29 20 34 33 37 3A 20 30 2E 30 34 33 34 36 36 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: fprintf shouldn't print zeroes. So if you have multiple threads there is some synchronization issue. So you should probably create a function which is protected by mutexes and fprintf only from there, so you can schedule the output appropriately. I.e. the threads print their data into memory to a string and put the output in a synchronized list. And your writer thread reads from that list and writes what is neccessary. Something like that.